# C:I am trying to find size of heap using malloc and realloc but getting infinite whats the exact solution for my program

Tags: c, heap-memory

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() { 
    int *p;
    int m=40;
    p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    while(realloc(p,10*sizeof(int))
        m=m+40;
    printf("Number of bytes allocated for heap",m);
}
```

what's wrong with this program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`realloc(p,10*sizeof(int)` always allocates the same range of memory. Change it to
`p = realloc(p,m*sizeof(int)`. If `realloc` succeeds it returns the pointer to the new dynamic memory by its return value, and the memory pointer passed to it gets freed (the data behind the pointer is moved from old memory to new memory). If `realloc` fails to allocate memory it returns `NULL`, no memory is allocated and no memory is freed. Further you should always `free` the allocated memory. Adapt your code like this:

```
int main() { 
    int *p = NULL;
    int  m = 40;
    int *newP;
    do
    {
        newP = realloc( p, m*sizeof( int ) );
        if ( newP != NULL )
            p = newP;
        m = m+40;
    }
    while ( newP != NULL );
    free( p );
    printf("Number of bytes allocated for heap",m);
}
```

Comment: The OP's earlier question was so poorly asked it was deleted by moderators. Essentially, this is the same. Plus 1, but I question your effect of re-using `p`. Doesn't it cause UB on the first reuse, after OP ignored the return value from `realloc`?

Comment: @WeatherVane I edited my code. (I think now it is obvious)

Answer (score 1):

1) You have a mistake in your `printf` format string, you need to actually tell it to print the integer you're passing: `%d` or `%i`

2) You're `realloc`ing the same number of bytes with every call, you need to increase it.

3) To be fully standards compliant, use `int main(void)`.

4) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) to find out why not to cast the result of `malloc` in C.

5) `realloc` can accept a `NULL` pointer and the result is well-defined, so your initial `malloc` call is not needed anyway.

6) Use a named constant + `sizeof(type/variable)` to make your code more robust and maintainable (and correct, because `sizeof(int)` need not be 4).

All these things combined, here's how I'd rewrite your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define REALLOC_NUM_ELEMENTS 10

int main(void) 
{
    int *p = NULL;
    int m = 0;

    while (p = realloc(p, (m + REALLOC_NUM_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int))))
        m += REALLOC_NUM_ELEMENTS * sizeof(int);

    printf("Number of bytes allocated for heap %d\n", m);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the returned value from `realloc`? Same mistake as question.

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean, don't use it? `realloc` returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory block, which I feed to `while` to see if the allocation was successful. I don't need to save it anywhere because I don't use the memory. Of course, maybe it would be better style to `free` it before I exit the program, but that really doesn't matter here.

Comment: I think you threw away the pointer. You have to feed it back into the next `realloc`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, true, didn't notice that, thanks.

Comment: thanks to all ................

Comment: k but getting negative value????????????????????y ?

Comment: @RanganayakiSrimathKandadai Maybe you're on a 64-bit operating system and as a result you can allocate > 2GB of memory? Try using `size_t` with the `%zu` format specifier.